Session Timeout on User side in Django
I am trying add a session timeout in my Django project by using Django's in-built session middleware. I have implemented session timeout on my project using the Views method I have come across for this purpose and it is working on my Admin side, but in my User side, the redirection that I given not working (i.e. I need to log out the user and get back to the signin page after session expires).
My django version : 5.0.2
My python version: 3.12.2
Now it is taking the time and that page will expire but it will not redirect to the signin page. How can I solve this issue?
What are some other approaches we can use for implementing Sessions on Admin & User sides both redirecting to the Signup page and persisting the last page worked on upon logging back in ?settings.pymiddilewareViews.pyurls.py

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. [edit] the question and include code fragments with the code sample button ({}).

It sounds like you wan the client-side to automatically sign-out the user when the session expires.  This can be accomplished in several ways.  The 2 most common methods are meta refresh and js timeout.
Let's say you have your session timeout set to 7200 (2 hours)
Method 1: Set a META tag in the head of your document to automatically refresh the page
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7200">

Method 2: Add some javascript code to perform a refresh after the time has expired
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload();
    },7200);
</script>

In both cases, assuming you have the @login_required decorator set on your view, when the page reloads, the user will be taken to the login page automatically.  You can also enhance the javascript approach by modifying the code to show a session timeout warning and giving the user time to respond and keep their session active.
